# PDB how to break on exit?

Tags: python, pdb

How can I get the python debugger, pdb to break on exit?
Also, why I am at it, How can I break on exceptions raised?

Answer (score 10):

Overwrite the function :

```
old_sys_exit = sys.exit
def new_sys_exit (value) : 
    print "in sys exit %s" % value
    old_sys_exit(value)
sys.exit = new_sys_exit
```

and then set the breakpoint :

```
(Pdb) b new_sys_exit
```

It works, also for other modules that call sys.

Comment: Is there a way to override ```sys.exit``` globally when running multi file python application?

Comment: @kanna you would do so in the beginning of the program. Multi file apps still have only one interpreter and one "sys" object.

Comment: If instead of setting a breakpoint on it, you have it raise a RuntimeError (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42835017/cathing-sys-exit-in-debugger), then you can do it directly from the debugger.