# Cathing sys.exit() in debugger

Tags: python, pdb

My programme ends unexpectedly.  When I run it through pdb, it ends with:

```
The program exited via sys.exit(). Exit status:
```

but then there is no record of the stack at the instance it exited.  I have no idea why it happens.  Short of `step` and `next`ing through everything, is there a way to instruct `pdb` to enter the debugger when this is attempted, instead of honouring the `sys.exit()`?

Answer (score 3):

A simple-ish solution would be to monkey-patch `sys.exit()` before running:

```
$ python -m pdb my_script.py

(Pdb) def no_exit(code): raise RuntimeError('halt')
(Pdb) import sys
(Pdb) sys.exit = no_exit
(Pdb) cont
```

Comment: I tried it but I'm still getting the same..  It seems pdb is lying to me?  Or perhaps it still reports `The program exited via sys.exit(). Exit status:` even if c-code ends the process bypassing `sys.exit()`?

Comment: @gerrit seems like pdb is assuming that because no exceptions were thrown, "SystemExit does not warrant a post-mortem session" https://svn.python.org/projects/sandbox/trunk/pdb/mpdb.py

Comment: Not sure how to "force" a post-mortem after a sys.exit :/ https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html "When invoked as a script, pdb will automatically enter post-mortem debugging if the program being debugged exits abnormally. After post-mortem debugging (or after normal exit of the program), pdb will restart the program."

Comment: What worked for me was to wrap the whole program in a try-except block  Probably there is a better way

Comment: @ChristabellaIrwanto If all you want is to drop to a console after your program runs, `python -i myscript.py` does the trick.

Comment: @AKX Thank you! The `-i` flag printed the full traceback while `-m pdb` only printed the final exit status and error message, which was unhelpful.